# How can I remove default headers that cURL sends?

Tags: curl, http-headers, content-type, x-www-form-urlencoded

Curl by default adds headers such as `Content-type` and `User-agent`. Normally that is a good thing but I'm trying to test what our server does when those headers are missing.

My problem is with the `Content-type` header. If it is missing, the server correctly assumes the user sent JSON. However, curl actually adds the missing header and incorrectly assumes that the content I am posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It also sends an Accept header of `*/*`.

I suppose that is nice default behavior but I basically would like it to not send headers I did not specify. Is there an option for that?

```
curl -v -X POST 'https://example.com' -d '{...}'

> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 299
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use `-H` flag with the header you want to remove and no content after the `:`

```
-H, --header LINE   Custom header to pass to server (H)
```

Sample

```
-H 'User-Agent:'
```

This will make the request ***without*** the `User-Agent` header (instead of sending it with an empty value)

Comment: For removing proxy headers, replace -H by --proxy-header, e.g. `--proxy-header "Proxy-Connection:"`

Comment: Using the standard Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) I had to replace the single quotes with double quotes (or remove them altogether).

Comment: `-H 'User-Agent:'` removes header as expected (no header and no value will be sent) but be careful with `-H 'Content-Type:'` which **will send header with empty value**. It is strange different behaviour of curl command.

Comment: Contrary to @mikep's experience, I found that (from libcurl, with version 7.63.0) setting "Content-Type:" as a header did completely remove that header from the request, at least according to a Wireshark capture.

Comment: I have `curl 7.66.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin) libcurl/7.66.0` and if I pass `-H 'Content-Type:'` as parameter it **does not** send `Content-Type` header.

Comment: One can use `-v` option passed to `curl` in order to see what exactly is being sent. Wireshark is a little bit too much for such a check. :)
Though it is probably more precise if some tool doesn't report things properly.

Answer (score 28):

Seems like `curl` sends 3 headers. To do a request without them you can append the arguments:

```
-H 'User-Agent:' -H 'Accept:' -H 'Host:'
```

+1 to @cmlndz answer as he explains how to remove a single header.

You can check which headers are actually sent by adding `-v`.

Comment: If your request has a body (like a POST request) it will also set `Content-Length: 433` or whatever the size of the body is. You can use `-H 'Content-Length:'` to exclude that header (although this likely leads to an invalid request as it should include the length or set the Transfer-Encoding header)

Comment: `-H 'Host:'` will most likely result in a "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid." You will also need to add the `--http1.0` parameter to the curl command.

Comment: What has to be done when for example, we need to prevent cURL from adding "Host" header by default yet send our own custom "host" header? Is it ideal to do something like this? ```-H 'Host:' -H 'host:www.example.com'```

Comment: @mang4521 I think you can just override it with single `-H 'Host:www.example.com'`. No need to remove then set. It will probably then just go down to parameter order precedence and be confusing.

Comment: @akostadinov I actually have tested this out. Overriding won't work here. We will have both the default and customised headers. In addition to this, what if I have a use case where I would not like to send a specific header yet curl will add it by default [say Accept-Encoding]?

Comment: @mang4521, not sure what version of curlt you are using. I just tried with `curl 7.82.0` and behavior is as I explained above.

Comment: @akostadinov even if we assume this works, what should we do when curl adds a header say ```Accept-Encoding``` by default and we would not want to override it? There should be a way to avoid adding these default headers all together. Would like to understand the nuances.

Comment: @mang4521, that's explained in the answer. To recap, if you want to remove, use what is given in the answer. If you want to change the header, just set it as I stated in my earlier comment. You don't have to assume, just try it out.

Comment: @akostadinov The following is what I have observed: (1) The default behaviour of curl is to add ```Host``` header at the beginning of the header list. (2) If ```host``` header is already present at the top, then curl will turn it to ```Host``` ie., case sensitivity. (3) If ```Host``` is present anywhere else apart from the top of the header list, curl will change the order of the header list and will bring ```Host``` to the top again.

Comment: @akostadinov your solution above does work when it comes to the requirement of removing a header added by curl by default. My question to you is, are there other ways of preventing default headers from being added by curl [apart from your solution above]?

Comment: @mang4521, `man curl` and read for yourself. I don't know what you're doing but you're doing something wrong. Or you use some strange/old `curl` version.