# JMeter - Why sending default User-Agent header

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x, user-agent, request-headers

When sending HTTP Request in JMeter, User-Agent header is added,e.g.:

> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_191)
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   Host: api.example.com

I didn't find any reason in documentation,

But there's a reference to its existence in [JMeter docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

> In this example, we created a Test Plan that tells JMeter to override the default "User-Agent" request header and use a particular Internet Explorer agent string instead.

When changing to Java in Advanced -> Implementation it doesn't send extra headers, so it's related to [HTTPClient4](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

> HttpClient sends a default User-Agent header with every request

But what is the reason behind it?

Also when I try to remove it, by adding User-Agent with empty value in Header Manager

Still it sends User-Agent with empty value, is there a way to avoid sending User-Agent header?

- Note in cUrl you can [remove default User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293181/how-can-i-remove-default-headers-that-curl-sends) using `curl --verbose -H 'User-Agent:'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which documentation? JMeter documentation shouldn't include comprehensive documentation on underlying [Java SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) (for `Java` implementation) or [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) for `HttpClient4` implementation.

For the latter one the "explanation" lives inside the [HttpClientBuilder](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.10/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.java#L1057) class

```
if (userAgentCopy == null) {
    if (systemProperties) {
        userAgentCopy = System.getProperty("http.agent");
    }
    if (userAgentCopy == null && !defaultUserAgentDisabled) { 
        userAgentCopy = VersionInfo.getUserAgent("Apache-HttpClient",
                "org.apache.http.client", getClass());
    }
}
```

If there is no [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header supplied the underlying Apache HttpComponents library implicitly adds the default header because clients SHOULD send the User-Agent string according to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43).

[Well-behaved JMeter test should represent real browser as close as possible](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) so given you see this default User-Agent string it indicates that your JMeter setup is not correct so your test results will not be reliable. Check out